# Browser save password show in wrong input

Tags: html, input, browser

This is login form

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
</form>
```

After login and save password by Browser, i go to users manage page

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="email" type="text" />
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
</form>
```

This page, browser show password and username by default to name and password

How fix it ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uniJY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZbTJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use different names in input tag
[How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Used autocomplete attribute of  tag.
read this link:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp

Comment: autocomplete for only input. this username and password saved by browser "manage password"

Comment: Hello @omid set id to your textbox value and call javascript onload function like this:                                                                           function f1()
{
        document.getElementById('email').value="";
 document.getElementById('name').value="";
}

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete. `autocomplete="off|on".`

"When autocomplete is on, the browser automatically complete values based on values that the user has entered before." [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp)

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <input name="email" type="text" />
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="psw" type="password" />
</form>
```

You shouls also use different input names.

Comment: autocomplete for only input. this username and password saved by browser "manage password"

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are actually looking for I don't think your question explains it correctly.

Comment: i add image to question